# Embedd Power BI report with free trial of Power BI Pro license in PHP

Tags: php, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I've been trying to show power bi report in my php project without the need for logging into power bi account.

Despite of everything that I have tried, [this is the last tutorial](https://www.alphabold.com/power-bi-embedded-implementation-using-service-principal-and-python/) that I really thought it would work, but it didn't.

With that tutorial, I was able to generate/get all credentials I need, such as: Service Principal, ClientId, TenantId, ClientSecret, WorkspaceId and ReportId.

I used the .net sample because I'm more familiar with it. I filled out all credential in the .net sample but when I run the project I get a "NotFound" error.

```
  "error": {
    "code": "PowerBIEntityNotFound",
    "pbi.error": {
      "code": "PowerBIEntityNotFound",
      "parameters": {},
      "details": [],
      "exceptionCulprit": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to debug it, how can I make sure that everything is set up in power bi, azure, and all credentials thing?

I tried [this](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/How-To-Get-embed-token-using-Get-Post-only/td-p/294475/page/1) as well, I was able to generate the access token but when try to get the report details trhough this API [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group-id}/reports/{report-id}/GenerateToken](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7Bgroup-id%7D/reports/%7Breport-id%7D/GenerateToken)
I get a 401 Unauthorized error.

At the end I'm lost of where to go. How can I achieve the initial goal?

Updates:

I followed the tutorial with a report that was at "My workspace" in https://app.powerbi.com/.
I've read that to make what I wanted I would need to create a new workspace, so I did and copied the report to the new workspace.
That also didn't work.
So I followed the tutorial I first mentioned strictly, i.e., I used the same report as it used, the covid one, and replicated the steps and it worked!

I'm thinking that the issue might be something related to the report, or the dataset, or how I'm connecting with the dataset.
I don't have knoledge in power bi concepts, but is there any restriction of how you do your reports or how do you connect with the datasource that would hinder you of embedding it? Or would it require some step that that tutorial didn't mention?

Comment: No need to move report into a new workspace. You can use [Get Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-report) API to get the report from my workspace

Comment: Refer [troubleshoot documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-troubleshoot#typical-errors-when-embedding-for-power-bi-users) as it is common error and reach out if you still faces the issue

Answer (score 1):

> The error **401 Unauthorized** might occur if you missed adding your service principal under Power BI workspace as `Admin` or `Contributor`.

Initially, I registered one Entra ID application named **`SriPowerBiEmbed`** and created one **client secret** in it like this:

[image]

Now, I generated one bearer token using **client credentials** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I tried to get the report details with below API, I too got ***401 Unauthorized*** error like this:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group-id}/reports/{report-id}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to add your **Entra ID app** to Power BI workspace with **Admin** access.

*Go to Power BI Portal -> Your Workspace -> Click on ... -> Manage access -> +Add people or groups -> Search for Service Principal with name -> Admin*

[image]

Additionally, check whether the access is **enabled or not** to use Power Bi APIs by checking Admin Portal like this:

[image]

Now, I generated the token again and got **response** with report details successfully when I call same Power BI API as below:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group-id}/reports/{report-id}
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can now create **Embed token** by calling below Power BI API with same bearer token like this:

```json
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group-id}/reports/{report-id}/GenerateToken
{
  "accessLevel": "View",
  "allowSaveAs": "true"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, it really makes sense, I tried again everything you said and no luck. I'm able to generate the token as in your first request. But the GET and POST to https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group-id}/reports/{report-id} I get a 404, No Http resource was found that maches the request URI [...]
Of course I'm changing the group and report ids.

Comment: I got same error 'No http resource was found' when I used POST for GET request. Check whether you are using right IDs or not while running `GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group-id}/reports/{report-id`

Comment: Could you include screenshots of error message and Power Bi Portal reports page to know whether you are using correct Ids or not, by editing your question?